# Location of The Below Mentioned IP Address and the domain name

Tags: windows, networking

I would like to know the exact location of this IP address 127.0.0.1 along with the domain name if possible and under whose name it is registered. If you can provide me with the address from where it is operated or even the area, would really appreciate.

Comment: You need to code a GUI in VB to trace the address.

Comment: This IP address seems to be operated by [Kamal Khokhani](http://superuser.com/users/195356/kamal-khokhani), click on that link to get all known information about that person.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia about [Loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback):

> In TCP/IP a loopback device is a virtual network interface implemented in software only and not connected to any hardware, but which is fully integrated into the computer system's internal network infrastructure. Any traffic that a computer program sends to the loopback interface is immediately received on the same interface.
>
> Correspondingly, the Internet Protocol (IP) specifies a loopback network. In IPv4 this is the network with the CIDR prefix 127.0.0.0/8 (RFC 3330). The most commonly used IP address on the loopback device is 127.0.0.1 for IPv4, although any address in the range 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 is mapped to it.

See also: [Localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/127.0.0.1)

Comment: Hi Alex! When quoting others, please use blockquotes to properly cite text you didn't write yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is known as the loop back address. So it actually exists on your machine.

It has a static entry in your computers host file that maps 127.0.0.1 to localhost

for more info see here

[Loopback/127.0.0.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

Comment: That's actually not fully correct. The whole 127.0.0.0/8 subnet is mapped to the NIC itself.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg true. I was attempting to provide an answer at or around the users level. without overloading on the detail. The link i provided does go onto address that.

Comment: @Steve - If one has to go the link contained in your post then your answer doesn't have enough information.  The link should only be used to cite your reference.

Comment: @Ramhound, the question asked specific about 127.0.0.1, which is 99.99% of the time refereed to as the loopback address. whilst there is an entire /8 address range that exists, my answer addresses his needs, and does not overload on the detail. the user really doesnt need to know about it

Answer (score 0):

alex p and steve have the technical answer - quite simply, 127.0.0.1 is a ip address that refers to your own system, and there shouldn't be any websites hosted on it by default. In most systems the 'domain name' localhost maps back to that IP address, and can be used to access any services you're running on it - typing localhost on a PC where you're running a webserver should connect to that webserver, and on a system there isn't, it should fail, the same way it would with an external system that dosen't run a web server.

From a comment to a deleted answer, you claim your AV is complaining about attack attempts from that IP address. There's two possibilities. Your AV is overreacting to a false positive, or you have malware. The former, you could probably look up on line. As for the latter, [we have a question specifically covering malware removal](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) - which is probably what you should be following up on.

The location of 127.0.0.1 is your desk, and the admin is *you*